# System protection against low memory crashes when not using swap

Tags: linux, memory, swap

What would be a good alternative whole-system-crash prevention method? Preferably not based on maximum (per-terminal) memory allocation limits but the other way around: some way to reserve enough memory for system (critical) processes (a few whitelisted processes). Or simply (put) some way to block running new processes when the system reaches some limit. Or at least some monitoring application with notifications/warnings.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for here but in limited environments tuning the `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` setting can be a last-resort effort to have some applications crash less or at least later.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to adjust the value of `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj` to prevent the oom killer to kill the process in case of low memory situation. Setting the value to `-1000` will prevent the kernel to kill the process completely.

Comment: I changed "crash" to "whole-system-crash". I hope this made my question clearer.